# SIte popularization and new users involving

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, search

Is there any ideas how the site could be promoted? It's already a lot of time in beta status, and statistics is not going to become better than it is. And everything okay but new quesions count — it is tot low. However I don't think there is another site where learning people could have more qualified answers for their questions.

I think there are much more people who need help with learning russian, but they just don't know / can't find this site. What's wrong with it?

My only guess is that site has not too much russian text. I mean, people who need help will most likely search for their question in russian language, creating *russian* search queries. And since most of the site's text is in english, he will never find it.

So, any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to promote our site?](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/162/how-to-promote-our-site)